# Replacement for ServerXMLHTTP30

Tags: asp.net, .net, serverxmlhttp

What is the best replacement for ServerXMLHTTP30 in .NET 3.5. Is HttpWebRequest good candidate? 
I am in the process of creating an application that will get a XML **stream** as a response to a request.
Appreciate any tips/help or guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. According to [Implement Common MSXML Tasks in System.xml By Using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/330589), the HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse classes in the System.net namespace provide the functionality of XMLHTTP in the .NET framework. ServerXMLHTTP shares similar APIs with XMLHTTP but uses WinHTTP stack.